Looking for the name of an old SF short story about a dictator
I read a SF short story in an anthology many years ago, and was hoping to find it again but can’t recall the maker or author.
In the story, some commandos are storming a fortress and making their way to fight a dictator who is in the fortress and is the enemy of mankind.
When the last commando survives and reaches the dictator, the dictator tells him that he will be the next dictator, and the humanity needs an enemy to bring them together.
I probably read this no later than 1980, so it’s an older book. Thanks for any help!

Cascade Point by Timothy Zahn - A frown had been growing steadily across Royd's forehead, in direct proportion to his confusion. "What's going on? Why are you telling me all this?" Grail's eyes bored into Royd's. "I want you to take over as head of state when I die." For a long moment there was dead silence in the room. "What?" Royd whispered at last. "You heard me. Rosette's developed about as far as it can under an absolute dictatorship. It needs to be nudged toward something more decentralized—a constitutional monarchy, perhaps, as a first step. But I can't do that."

The story from Cascade Point is Dragon pax but it doesn't have any commandos storming a fortress.

@JohnRennie - Aye. Not a great match, hence why posted as a comment

is this a version of the "prepare two envelopes" joke?

This sounds like "Satan"s Shrine" (1954) by Daniel F. Galouye.  Originally published in Galaxy, it can be read at the Internet Archive.
In the story the titular "Satan," the  supreme autocrat of Earth, rules the world from a massive bunker complex with production facilities that constantly churn out nuclear missile and interceptors.  He has a 4000 year supply of food, so he can't be starved out.  Underground elements in various nations periodically send commando teams into the bunker to kill him.
It was anthologised in Terrorists of Tomorrow (1986).

Hey that’s amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for!
Thanks so much for helping me out, I never would’ve found this again!
